# New Ubuntu install, now reboot startup screen shows ethernet controller for 1 minute

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an older computer that I had recently upgraded with a SSD and new graphics card.

The install worked, however when I reboot I get the following screen for about 1 minute.
[image]

After about a minute I see this and then ubuntu boots normally 2-3 seconds later

[image]

How can I avoid or eliminate this ?

Comment: It seems the Computer  try to start over ethernet. Make your Harddrive in Bios/Efi is at 1. place in boot order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BIOS setting you have boot order. In the boot order you have 'network' over 'harddisk'. Move 'network' down and it will work.